# The conjunction "dass" and "wenn"

Tags: grammar, style, conjunction

> Ich weiß nicht genau, dass, wenn er in den Supermarkt ohne sie geht, sie sauer auf ihn wird.

Can "dass" be with other conjunctions be in one sentence? My book says that " dass" should be followed immediately by another conjuction. But i dont know if the sentence I wrote is grammatically acceptable or is used in regional dialects. Here's another sentence:

> Sie sagte, ohne darüber zu denken, dass, wenn sie die jeden Tag nicht in die Schule geht, sie ein Monat kein Hausarrest kriegen wird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ja, das kann man in etwa so schreiben, ich finde es aber unnötig verschachtelt.

Wenn Du das erste Beispiel umformulierst, wird es etwas klarer: "Ich weiß genau, dass sie sauer auf ihn sein wird, wenn er ohne sie in den Supermarkt geht". Oder meinst Du "Ich weiß nicht genau, ob sie sauer auf ihn sein wird, wenn er ohne sie in den Supermarkt geht"?

Im zweiten Beispiel scheint das "nicht" zu fehlen, was im ersten zu viel ist: "Sie sagte, ohne darüber nachzudenken, dass sie, wenn sie (nicht) jeden Tag in die Schule geht, einen Monat Hausarrest kriegen wird." Auch hier würde ich es umstellen und schreiben "Sie sagte, ohne darüber nachzudenken, dass sie einen Monat Hausarrest kriegen wird, wenn sie nicht jeden Tag in die Schule geht."

Answer (score 3):

More correctly 'dass' must be combined with another conjunction in the following subset of the sentence (Teilsatz), however that conjuction does not neccessarily have to be right behind 'dass', as Robert already showed by first putting the consequence (sie sauer auf ihn wird) and then stating the condition (wenn er...).

Additionally you might want to read about Parenthesises ([Wiki: Parenthese /  Einschub](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einschub)).